# Connected complete metric spaces with more than one point.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Does every connected complete metric space with more than one point have infinitely many closed balls?  And is any closed ball in a connected complete metric space connected?

Comment: The answer to the second question is no. Remove a single point from a circle and consider a small ball near the removed point.

Comment: What about completeness?

Comment: Fine, remove a small open ball.

Comment: @mfl: the circle is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, hence complete; or am I misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @Matt when you remove a point it is no longer complete, so removing an open ball is necessary to preserve completeness.

Comment: @DanielRust: Sorry for my obtuseness, are you saying that the little ball near the removed open ball is not connected? How exactly?

Comment: @DanielRust: my bad; thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @user156619 a closed ball with center near the removed segment of the circle (and whose radius is larger than the diameter of the removed segment) would be homeomorphic to the disjoint union of two intervals.

Comment: @DanielRust---thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. Take distinct points $a,b\in X$. For $0<r<d_X(a,b)$ there is a point $c\in X$ such that $d(a,c)=r$; indeed, otherwise $X$ would be the union of disjoint   open sets $\{x:d(a,x)<r\}$ and $\{x:d(a,x)> r\}$.  Therefore, all closed balls $\{x:d(a,x)\le r\}$, $0<r<d_X(a,b)$ are distinct sets.
2. No. An example was given in comments. For another example, remove the open rectangle $(-10,10)\times (0,1)$ from $\mathbb R^2$; keep the metric the same. The closed ball of radius $2$ centered at $(0,0)$ is not connected.

By the way, completeness was not used in the proof of 1.